# unable to start springboot server generated from swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-editor

I am new to swagger, i had to write swagger for a given POJO (just POJO) and implement API for it. So by using [swagger editor](http://editor.swagger.io/#/) I was able to write swagger processed with no errors and then did
1. Generate Server from menu and selected spring
2. Generate Client from menu and selected client

I opened the generated java API client and build successfully.
I opened the generated spring server in IntelliJ and try to run the server and I got below error ...

```
2016-08-18 17:16:53.188  INFO 17456 --- [           main] io.swagger.Swagger2SpringBoot            : Starting Swagger2SpringBoot on AMUSLT17507 with PID 17456 (C:\Users\SGattu1\Downloads\spring-server-generated\spring-server\target\classes started by SGattu1 in C:\Users\SGattu1\Downloads\spring-server-generated\spring-server)
2016-08-18 17:16:53.216  INFO 17456 --- [           main] io.swagger.Swagger2SpringBoot            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-08-18 17:16:53.337  INFO 17456 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6d3af739: startup date [Thu Aug 18 17:16:53 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-18 17:16:55.535 ERROR 17456 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:612) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at io.swagger.Swagger2SpringBoot.main(Swagger2SpringBoot.java:24) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
... 27 common frames omitted
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything over here, appreciate your help.

## EDITED

#### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-spring</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>swagger-spring</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <springfox-version>2.5.0</springfox-version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--SpringFox dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I try to generate spring server for the examples `default, heroku, instagram, twitter` they have provided and for these also getting same error.

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml? It looks like a dependency is missing.

Comment: Please open an issue via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new so that the swagger codegen community can help you further.

Comment: @ShawnClark I have added the pom.xml,, please let me know if it is missing any dependencies.

Comment: @wing328 sure I will open issue as this is happening for the examples they have provided

Comment: When you say you are trying to run the server... What steps / commands are you using to run it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the `provided` scope for tomcat. This would assume that you are deploying the app into an existing tomcat instance. Can you try removing that scope, refresh the project, and try running again?

Comment: I tried removing the `provided` for tomcat and it worked :) thanks a lot

Comment: I am still having issues even though the server is running. I have created my sample REST api and added swagger dependencies and able to GET requests and /api-docs ...
but the generated code I get 404 not found for /api-docs and /myservice . DO I need to change anything in the generated code?

Comment: I am not sure as I am not as familiar with how swagger works. I would recommending a new question specific around swagger generated code as the initial question was resolved. You will get more visibility if you target the question around "swagger generated code".